# How can I restart a failed PBS job in cluster (qsub)?

Tags: python-3.x, pbs, qsub, torque

I'm running a **PBS** job (python) in the cluster using **qsub** command. I'm curious to know how can I restart the same job from the step where it failed? 
Any type of help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you cannot.

Restarting a job requires a checkpoint file.
For this, checkpointing support has to be explicitly configured on your HPC environment and then the job has to be submitted with additional command-line arguments.

See
http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/torque/3-0-5/2.6jobcheckpoint.php